# Understanding groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to get the sum of some values in a dataframe after it has been grouped.

some sample data:

```
Race          officeID   CandidateId  total_votes   precinct
Mayor         10         705            20           Bell
Mayor         10         805            30           Bell
Treasurer     12         505            10           Bell
Treasurer     12         506            40           Bell
Treasurer     12         507            30           Bell
Mayor         10         705            50           Park
Mayor         10         805            10           Park
Treasurer     12         505            5            Park
Treasurer     12         506            13           Park
Treasurer     12         507            16           Park
```

To get the sum of the votes for each candidate, I can do:

```
cand_votes = df.groupby('CandidateId').sum().total_votes
print cand_votes

CandidateId
505    15
506    53
507    46
705    70
805    40
```

To get total votes per office:

```
total_votes = df.groupby('officeID').sum().total_votes
print total_votes

officeID
10    110
12    114
```

But what if I want to get the percentage of the vote each candidate got? Would I have to apply some sort of function on each data object? Ideally I would like the final data object to look like:

```
officeID    CandidateID    total_votes    vote_pct
10          705            70             .6363
10          805            40             .37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a frame that that has the votes by candidate and office.

```
gb = df.groupby(['officeID','CandidateId'], as_index=False)['total_votes'].sum()
```

Then with that, you can aggregate by office and use a transform (which returns like indexed data) to calculate a percent of office.

```
gb['vote_pct'] = gb['total_votes'] / gb.groupby('officeID')['total_votes'].transform('sum')


In [146]: gb
Out[146]: 
   officeID  CandidateId  total_votes  vote_pct
0        10          705           70  0.636364
1        10          805           40  0.363636
2        12          505           15  0.131579
3        12          506           53  0.464912
4        12          507           46  0.403509
```