# groupby by years and generate new columns

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the following info about number of trades done in the past and I group them by year:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('19990101', periods=6000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(6000,2)), index = dates)
df.columns = ['winners','losers']
grouped = df.groupby(lambda x: x.year)
print grouped.sum()
```

How can I generate one column in this "grouped" data that shows the percentage winners per year? and another column that shows the maximum consecutive losing trades per year?

Was trying to follow this example [Understanding groupby in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150052/understanding-groupby-in-pandas), but couldn't figure out in my case how to do it by year.

Comment: When you say percentage winners, do you mean #winners/total trades?  The maximum consecutive losing trades per year, are you trying to do a rolling sum of losers until you hit a zero?  It might help to show the desired output with a simple set of data.

Comment: Hi, yes. Sorry for not being clear. 
Percentage winners = #winners/total trades. 
Lets say each date shows the number of losing trades done during that date. So for example if we had the following losers: 02jan2000 = 1, 03jan2000 = 4, 04jan2000 = 0, 05jan2000=15
then Still the max "consecutive losers" in year 2000 would be 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly Create a new DataFrame, then create necessary column according winners and losers:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df ['winners'] = df.groupby(df.index.year, as_index=True)['winners'].sum()
new_df ['losers'] = df.groupby(df.index.year, as_index=True)['losers'].sum()
```

Then with that, you can aggregate by winners, losers (which returns like indexed data) to calculate a percent of winners, losers.

You can do it like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('19990101', periods=6000)
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randint(0,50,size=(6000,2)), index = dates)
df.columns = ['winners','losers']
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df ['winners'] = df.groupby(df.index.year, as_index=True)['winners'].sum()
new_df ['losers'] = df.groupby(df.index.year, as_index=True)['losers'].sum()
new_df['winners_Percent'] = new_df['winners']/new_df['winners'].sum()
new_df['losers_Percent'] = new_df['losers']/new_df['losers'].sum()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. The new DataFrame was the key!
I'll try to figure out the consecutive losers by myself now that I know this little trick.